# How do you change an eqaution to y=ax^2+bx+c (standard form) Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to take this equation: $y=(x-3)^2-2$ and turn it into $y=ax^2+bx+c$  (standard form). Can anyone help me step by step how to change this?

Edit: Math tex-style

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried? A good start would be to distribute $(x - 3)^2$.

Comment: @T.Bongers So if I distribute it, is this what I'm supposed to get (x^2 + 9) ?

Comment: No: It is *not* true that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$. Perhaps you've heard of "FOIL"?

Comment: $(a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b)=a^2-ab-ab+b^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$.

Comment: @T.Bongers  Thank You! Now I understand. I wasn't thinking about the foil system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $y=(x-3)^2-2 = (x-3)(x-3)-2 =(x^2-3x-3x+9) - 2 = (x^2-6x+9)-2 = x^2-6x+7$.

Comment: How did you get that 9? (x2−3x−3x+9) <- that nine

Comment: $-3 \cdot -3 = --9 = 9$

Comment: Why would you add the x to the both -3? That part is confusing me.